# Redirect Rewrite rule Working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Rewriting

```
example.com/about-us?pageID=1 to example.com/about-us
```

Tried below rules and also others but nothing seems to work

```
Redirect 301 /about-us?pageID=1  http://example.com/about-us
```

This one works but disturbs other links also

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pageID=1
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/about-us? [R=301,L]
```

There are other pages with `about-us/pageid` and also `product/pageID` and those need not be disturbed i need to redirect this particular link only.

Comment: You want to redirect or rewrite?

Comment: redirect the link

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve `example.com/about-us` using this rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about-us$ /about-us?pageID=1 [L]
```

Just make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: no this didnt work i need to redirect /about-us?pageID=1  to /about-us

Comment: Perhaps reword your question. Considering it says **Rewrite** followed by the two URLs.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect that specific URL (essentially just removing the query string) you should include a `RewriteRule` *pattern* to match the URL-path (as you did for the `Redirect` directive).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageID=1$
RewriteRule ^(about-us)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

As you found, you need to use mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteCond`) in order to match the query string.

The `$1` is simply a backreference to the matched group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* ie. "about-us". This just avoids having to repeat "about-us".

Clear your browser cache before testing, since the earlier 301s will have been cached. For this reason it is often easier to test with temporary (302) redirects.

Comment: always cleared cache but no riles rules are not working 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageID=([1]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /about-us? [L,R=301]

Comment: Have you tried the directives in my answer? The rules you just quoted are unlikely to work as they will redirect _every URL_ with a query string parameter.

Comment: The above directive wouldn't do anything if the link included the `.php` extension (ie. `/about-us.php?...`) - or do you mean if you changed the directive to match? It's just that you stated that the directive in your question "works but disturbs other links". If the directive in your question "worked" then this should also "work". Make sure your browser cache is clear (301s are cached hard by the browser). Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: there are many rewrite rules in .htaccess 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pageID=1
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/about-us? [R=301,L] 
 rewrite all other link also as product?pageId=1 to /about-us

Comment: If the directive/rule in my answer is not "doing anything" then there may be a clash with your existing directives. Order matters. Please add your  `.htaccess` file (with these directives in place) to your question.